# How to run a parameterized suite file from command line using maven

Tags: maven, selenium, intellij-idea, webdriver, testng

I am trying to find out how to run a parameterized suite file from command line using maven. I am using IntelliJ to write my webdriver tests and in that IDE I just right click on the suite file and click run xml which sends the parameters in the suite file to my base class which all of my test cases extend and then it runs my tests. Is there a way to run the same parameterized suite file from command-line. I use this command to run a suite-file from command-line

```
 mvn test -Dtests=resources/test-suites/audioSuite.xml     

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="Image Upload Suite Firefox" verbose="1" >
      <test name="Image Upload Test" parallel="false">
      <parameter name="BROWSER" value="FF" />
      <parameter name="VERSION" value="20" />
      <parameter name="PLATFORM" value="WINDOWS" />
      <parameter name="NAME" value="Simple Image Upload Test" />
        <classes>
          <class name="audioTestsNodeFormPlus.xxxxxx"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
  </suite>
```

The base class looks like this -

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"BROWSER","VERSION","PLATFORM","NAME"})
public  void setup(String BROWSER, int VERSION, String PLATFORM, String NAME) throws   IOException {
    if (BROWSER.equals("FF")) {
        DesiredCapabilities capabillities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabillities.setCapability("version", VERSION);
        capabillities.setCapability("platform", Platform.valueOf(PLATFORM));
        capabillities.setCapability("selenium-version", "2.32.0");
        capabillities.setCapability("name", NAME);
```

Comment: The first thing is your tests are integration tests and *not* unit tests so using the test lifecycle (or maven-surefire-plugin) is wrong. You should go with the maven-failsafe-plugin which is intended for integration tests. Furthermore you class is neither named to the naming conventions for [unit tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) nor for [integration tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes).

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise i will try using the maven-failsafe-plugin and see if my tests runs. With mvn test -Dsuitefile my test runs but nothing happens. I think the issue is with the suitefile passing parameters to the baseclass and the baseclass not accepting it. If I dont use the baseclass then all runs fine